# Magento and Akeneo

Tags: extensions

I am contacting you because i would like to get some advice from you. 
We are a young french startup who sells products on amazon mainly.
Actually, our product catalog is on excel and we just import it with no intermediate, on amazon.
So, we would like to create an architecture more efficient.
We would like first export our product catalog from excel to a PIM (Akeneo), then export from the PIM to an ecommmerce platform (Magento) and then export from the ecommerce platform to marketplaces.
Could you give us some advices ?
We installed Akeneo but we have some problems to import from excel to akeneo ? do we need a special connector for the import ?
From the PIM to Magento, there is the PIMgento connector. Do you know it ? Any recommandations ?
And from Magento to Marketplaces,  there are two options : we can use a connector or a tool like Lengow. Any recommandations too ? what is the most interesting. We dont really care about the cost.

I  hope all is enough clear.

Answer (score 1):

> Could you give us some advices ?

No. I'm just starting.

> We installed Akeneo but we have some problems to import from excel to akeneo? do we need a special connector for the import?

Yes, afaik there is a excel import: https://github.com/akeneo-labs/ExcelConnectorBundle

> From the PIM to Magento, there is the PIMgento connector. Do you know it?

I'm, just trying it out. But this is no real question.

> Any recommandations ? And from Magento to Marketplaces, there are two options : we can use a connector or a tool like Lengow. Any recommandations too ? what is the most interesting. We dont really care about the cost.

There is M2epro, but I would really think about directly exporting from PIM to the marketplaces. More system means more complexity